# How to modify a child only if a certain sibling exists?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Going by the attached code, I am trying to have the sibling elements, where they exist, move to a different position, namely inside the related child, within their parent. So that once the button is clicked, all siblings will move to be inside their related children.

I've previously gotten the moving of the element to work, but that made it so that the siblings would move to a previous parent if their parent didn't have any relevant children, meaning that all the siblings would cluster together in all the top parents and not their corresponding parent. Hope that makes sense...

```js
function appendSibling() {
  console.log("appendSibling()");
  var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
  var siblings = document.getElementsByClassName('sibling');
  var children = document.getElementsByClassName('child');

  for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; ++i) {
    if (parents[i].querySelector('.sibling')) {
      parents[i].querySelector('.child').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', parents[i].querySelector('.sibling'));
    }
  }
}
```

```css
  .parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
}

.sibling {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling">Num 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling">Num 2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
<button class="button" onclick="appendSibling()">
</button>
```

Comment: The sibling are already adjacent to the child, can you clarify the requirement more

Comment: @BiswajitSharma For clarity, I suppose you could imagine that the sibling is supposed to go inside the child instead. I can edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: I tried to answer but I'm not perfectly sure I got it right. I just modified slightly your code so that all the `.sibling` get moved inside the `.child` element found on the same `.parent`. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using insertAdjacentElement (position argument):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement?retiredLocale=it

> - 'beforebegin': Before the targetElement itself.
> - 'afterbegin': Just inside the targetElement, before its first child.
> - 'beforeend': Just inside the targetElement, after its last child.
> - 'afterend': After the targetElement itself.

### Inverting the position of .child and .sibling in their .parent:

If you meant to invert the position of `.child` and `.sibling` elements inside their `.parent`, it was correct to use `afterend` like this:

```
const destination = parents[i].querySelector('.child');
const elementToMove = parents[i].querySelector('.sibling');
destination.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', elementToMove);
```

Of course in your snippet your styles position the element in absolute way. So you won't see any difference in the viewport but if you inspect the elements you'll see that now the `.sibling` element will be next to the `.child` element after clicking the button that performs the transformation.

### Moving .sibling inside the .child of the same .parent:

It wasn't clear at first in the question, but it seems you wished instead to move the `.sibling` element ***inside*** the `.child` of the same `.parent`.

In that case `beforeend` was more appropriate:

```
const destination = parents[i].querySelector('.child');
const elementToMove = parents[i].querySelector('.sibling');
destination.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', elementToMove);
```

### Demo working with the second approach:

```js
function appendSibling() {
  console.log("appendSibling()");
  var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
  var siblings = document.getElementsByClassName('sibling');
  var children = document.getElementsByClassName('child');

  for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; ++i) {
    if (parents[i].querySelector('.sibling')) {
      const destination = parents[i].querySelector('.child');
      const elementToMove = parents[i].querySelector('.sibling');
      destination.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', elementToMove);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
}

.sibling {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling">Num 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling">Num 2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<button class="button" onclick="appendSibling()">
</button>
```